# How to lookup child elements in ember model?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Here are the two models that i have defined

```
//Plugin model
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name:    DS.attr('string'),
  account: DS.hasMany('account')
});

//account model
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  username: DS.attr('string'),
  plugin  : DS.attr('plugin')
});


// Plugin Route
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.findAll('plugin');
  }
});


//Accounts route
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return this.store.findRecord('account',params.id);
  }
});
```

The api structure to list accounts associated with a plugin is `/plugins/:id/accounts`.The problem is i am unable to make request to the same using above code. `params.id` in case above is id for `plugin` and not `account`. Is there something i am missing out on emberjs or should i change my api to bring accounts to root ?

Answer (score 0):

First, this is wrong:

```
plugin  : DS.attr('plugin')
```

probably you mean:

```
plugin  : DS.belongsTo('plugin')
```

Also you maybe should pluralize this:

```
account: DS.hasMany('account')
```

to this:

```
accounts: DS.hasMany('account')
```

Next you need to understand that `ember-data` gives you a very complex abstraction. First make sure to specify the related link in your serializer. So your serializer for the `findAll('plugin')` should return this:

```
{
    data: {
        type: 'plugin',
        id: '1',
        attributes: {
            name: 'foo'
        },
        relationships: {
            accounts: {
                links: {
                    related: '/plugins/1/accounts'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you have an account instance, you can just `.get('plugins')`. Now if you pass the right `id` to the `{{link-to}}` helper, this will work:

```
return this.store.findRecord('plugin', params.id).then(plugin => plugin.get('accounts'));
```

However for this you also need a way to load a single plugin when you use deep-linking. The alternative is to use `query` and do it by hand.